# График из библиотеки chart js не отображает данные принимаемые из fetch

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, chart.js

Строится график, но он не отображает, то что я принимаю в fetch, если прописать значения data или labels вручную всё нормально, но то что в fetch игнорируется, при этом данные 100% получаю в console.log всё выводится, думаю тут что то связано с асинхронным программированием

```
var data = {labels: ["1", "2", '3'], datasets: []};
var dataset = {
    label: "Температура",
    data: [],

}

async function getData() {
    let resp = await fetch("someUrl")
    let json = await resp.json();
    for (i in json.Dht22) {
        data.labels.push(json.Dht22[i].date.slice(11, 19));
        dataset.data.push(json.Dht22[i].temperature);

    }
}
getData();
data.datasets.push(dataset);
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: options
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё решилось добавлением асинхронной функции, где можно сделать `await getData();`

```
async function chartIt() {
    await getData();
    data.datasets.push(dataset);
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: data,
        options: options
    });

}
```